# Adding GIF image to SCNNode causes screen to freeze in Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios11, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, xcode9.1

I am adding GIF image to SCNNode like below:

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 2, height: 2)

let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "engine", withExtension: "gif")
let animation : CAKeyframeAnimation = createGIFAnimation(url: bundleURL!)!
let layer = CALayer()
layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 900)

layer.add(animation, forKey: "contents")
let tempView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 900))
tempView.layer.bounds = CGRect(x: -450, 
                               y: -450, 
                           width: tempView.frame.size.width, 
                          height: tempView.frame.size.height)

tempView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

let newMaterial = SCNMaterial()
newMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
newMaterial.diffuse.contents = tempView
plane.materials = [newMaterial]
let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
node.name = "engineGif"
let gifImagePosition = SCNVector3Make((self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].position.x)! + 2, 
                                      (self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].position.y)! + 4, 
                                      (self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].position.z)! - 2))

node.position = gifImagePosition
self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].addChildNode(node)
```

Everthing looks fine and I am able to view the GIF image with animation. But when I try to move to previous view controller using PopViewController method, I am able to navigate to previous screen but the screen freezes there and none of the button click works.

If I put the app in background and come again, everything works as intended.

I tried removing the GIF image before pop but still have same issue. If I don't add the GIF image, everything is working fine. So the issue is only with adding GIF and I couldn't figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. If i set tempView.layer as contents, it is working fine instead of tempView like below,

```
        let newMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        newMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
        newMaterial.diffuse.contents = tempView.layer
        plane.materials = [newMaterial]
```

Do not know why it is but this worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem because I load a UIView but un my case I cant use a layer any idea?

Comment: I can interact inside the UIView.. However top navigation bar not working.. Do u have any idea?